# How to see $P(X_{i_1} = x_{i_1}, X_{i_2}=x_{i_2}, \ldots, X_{i_j} = x_{i_j}) = P(X_{i_1} = x_{i_1})P(X_{i_1} = x_{i_1}) \dots P(X_{i_j} = x_{i_j})$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are independent random variables.

Then by definition $P(X_i = x_i, X_j = x_j) = P(X_i = x_i)P(X_j = x_j)$ for $i \neq j$.

I've the following questions:

How do I see that $$P(X_{i_1} = x_{i_1}, X_{i_2}=x_{i_2}, \ldots, X_{i_j} = x_{i_j}) = P(X_{i_1} = x_{i_1})P(X_{i_1} = x_{i_1}) \dots P(X_{i_j} = x_{i_j})$$ where $i_n \neq i_m$ for $n,m \in \{1, \ldots, j \}$.

I've tried induction, but not come to a conclusion.

Also, how do I see that $$P((X_{i_1} = x_{i_1}, X_{i_2}=x_{i_2}, \ldots, X_{i_{j-1}} = x_{i_{j-1}}),X_{i_j} = x_{i_j}) = P(X_{i_1} = x_{i_1}, X_{i_2}=x_{i_2}, \ldots, X_{i_{j-1}} = x_{i_{j-1}})P(X_{i_j} = x_{i_j})$$ where $i_n \neq i_m$ for $n,m \in \{1, \ldots, j \}$. (that is, if I collect some random variables in a vector then indepence is preserved)

Comment: This is the definition of (joint) independence. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If $(X_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ are independent then by definition: $$P(X_{\alpha_1}\leq x_{\alpha_1},\dots,X_{\alpha_n}\leq x_{\alpha_n})=P(X_{\alpha_1}\leq x_{\alpha_1})\times\cdots\times P(X_{\alpha_n}\leq x_{\alpha_n})$$ for *any* finite subset $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ of $A$ where the $\alpha_i$ are distinct.

According to your 'definition' the $X_{\alpha}$ are only *mutual independent* which is weaker. In general it does not imply independence.

Comment: Isn't your definition the definition of mutual independence ? - or how is your definition stated ?

Comment: Independence is connected with *any* finite subset of $A$ (my definition). Mutual independent is connected with every ordered pair $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle$ with $\alpha,\beta\in A$ and $\alpha\neq\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you are trying to prove is in fact the definition of independence of a set of random variables. It is not sufficient if every pair of rv is independent, so there is no implication from the product of two to the product of j.

The second one is just a notation question. When you write: $$ X_i = x_i, X_j = x_j $$
it means formally: $$ X_i = x_i \wedge X_j = x_j $$ and the conjunction is associative :) so you can just drop the parenthesis.